# Disable Cmd+Enter on iTerm 2

Tags: macos, iterm2

I'm using iTerm 2 on Mac, and whenever I press Command + Return the thing goes full screen.
My big fat fingers can't help it, so I really need to turn it off. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Waiting a few seconds for the stupid animation just killed it for me. (the animation is cool when you actually want full-screen).

Comment: Slack broke my brain training me to use Command-Return. I set iterm to ignore and then went to Slack and set "Show send button" off so I can train my brain properly again.

Comment: Simply try restarting your brain

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Set <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> to `Ignore` in the iTerm 2 preferences.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Note, you have to add this entry using the + at the bottom. It isn't there by default.

Comment: Intuitive /s ...

Comment: As of iTerm 2 version 3.3.6, it's under Preferences > Keys > Key Bindings (it's not labelled 'global shortcut keys' any more).

Comment: If you set it to 'send hex code' instead of ignore, and set the hex code to `0x0D` it will actually send the return char through to the terminal instead of just ignoring.

Answer (score 4):

You can also change shortcuts from System Preferences:

[image]

Or by editing property lists:

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Toggle Full Screen' '^@f'
defaults write -app iTerm NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Toggle Full Screen"="\0";}'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on High Sierra :(

Comment: Check my answer here, I have solved this problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427416/419437